# Determining unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ that is upper triangular with eigenvalues along the main diagonal. My question is, can we explicitly construct a unitary matrix $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ so that we can permute the eigenvalues on the diagonal anyway we like? Let $n=2$ for simplicity. Here
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & x \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{pmatrix}.$$
And we want to find $U$ such that $U \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ such that
$$U^*AU = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_2 & y \\
0 & \lambda_1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now, I know this has to be true by Schur's Theorem, but the construction seems a bit challenging. Multiplying the matrices and equating term-by-term is what I initially had in mind, but this led nowhere. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit construction for the general case is probably not worth the trouble. However, the explicit construction for the $n = 2$ case is simple enough. I assume that $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$; if the eigenvalues are equal, there is no real "permutation" to make and we could simple choose $U = I$.

As in the proof of Schur's theorem, we note that the first column of $U$ should be an eigenvalue of $A$ associated with $\lambda_2$. Note that
$$
A - \lambda_2 I = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 & x\\ 0 & 0}.
$$
We can see that one eigenvector associated with $\lambda_2$ is given by
$$
v = (x, \lambda_2 - \lambda_1).
$$
In order to make this a column of $U$, this vector must be normalized. Accordingly, we can take the first column of $U$ to be
$
u_1 = v/\|v\|.
$
With that, we have
$$
u_{11} = x/\sqrt{|x|^2 + |\lambda_1 - \lambda_2|^2}, \quad
u_{21} = (\lambda_2 - \lambda_1)/\sqrt{|x|^2 + |\lambda_1 - \lambda_2|^2}.
$$
From there, the second column must be a unit vector orthogonal to the first column. So, there must be an $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ with $|\alpha| = 1$ such that
$$
u_{12} = \alpha (\overline{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2})/\sqrt{|x|^2 + |\lambda_1 - \lambda_2|^2} = -\alpha \bar u_{21}, \\
u_{22} = \alpha \bar x /\sqrt{|x|^2 + |\lambda_1 - \lambda_2|^2} = \alpha \bar u_{22}.
$$
In order to find a suitable value of $\alpha$, note that the $1,2$ entry of $U^*AU$ is given by
$$
x = \pmatrix{\bar u_{11} & \bar u_{21}} A \pmatrix{u_{12}\\ u_{22}} = \\
\alpha \cdot \pmatrix{\bar u_{11} & \bar u_{12}} A \pmatrix{-\bar u_{21}\\\bar u_{11}} =\\
\alpha \cdot \frac{1}{|x|^2 + |\lambda_1 - \lambda_2|^2} \cdot 
\pmatrix{\bar x & \overline{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}} A \pmatrix{\overline{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}\\\bar x}.
$$
In other words, if $x$ is non-zero, then $\alpha$ must be taken to be $\alpha = e^{-i \theta}$, where $\theta$ is the argument of the number
$$
\frac{1}{x(|x|^2 + |\lambda_1 - \lambda_2|^2)} \cdot 
\pmatrix{\bar x & \overline{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}} A \pmatrix{\overline{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}\\\bar x}.
$$